# When server data need to refresh in application

Tags: android, database, caching, retrofit2

After fetching data from server we can store that in `DataBase` and use that again and again and refresh data if that modified in server like this diagram:

[image]

**BUT** how to found out about server data need to refresh in app **without request again**?

**note :** I found some solution like `push` model but i think `HTTP` in `rest api` can resolve this problem, something like `@HEAD` or *etc*.

Comment: you can check real time database in firebase

Comment: i want to use my server responses

Comment: firebase shows everything (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679460/how-to-include-source-cache-in-cloud-firestore-realtime-update-in-mvvm-architect)

Comment: i want to use custom server, not firestore,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no guarantee that the push will be received

The first solution: you need a **hash** or **timestamp**. When there is new data on your server, it will update this hash or timestamp. Then you need to check if this hash or timestamp matches. If not, you need to update the data..

Comment: we can use this idea in HEAD request and check change data , and after modified data update date , yes?

Comment: You also can research about [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Push Technology** , in which server side sends info when it has new updated info..

in other words we can say **"publish and subscribe"** model..

Comment: I found some solution like push model but i think rest api can resolve this problem, something like @HEAD or etc.

Comment: @Ali Vatanparast yes you can use HEAD.. but you dont want to use request again.. thats why i mentioned about push technology

Comment: HEAD request do not receive body in response , that is really useful here, we can use head request for check change data and after that use original request , yes?

Comment: Yes. HEAD is also request.. only difference is server not need to write response body while taking action on HEAD.. it sends status in header.. if there is any change in data then you can return 200